# How can I add a not_analyzed field into Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

As of now I am using NEST to index the data into Elasticsearch.
When I am trying to index one of the field as `not_analyzed` using the following code:

```
 var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                node,
                defaultIndex: "resourceid5_analyzed1"
            )
            .SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p => p);

            var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
            var response = client.Map<GoodDataAttribute>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()
                .Properties(props => props
                .String(s1 => s1
                .Name(p => p.ResourceGroup)
                .Analyzer("keyword")
                .IncludeInAll(false)
                .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
                .OmitNorms(true))));
```

I have used `SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer` to disable the camel case of elastic property
I am using NEST version 1.7
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to update an existing mapping, then you cant change an existing field from "analyzed" to "not_analyzed".

to do it, you need to delete your index

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#updating-a-mapping

Comment: Till now index has not been created.
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                node,
                defaultIndex: "resourceid5_analyzed1"
            )
            .SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p => p);
Here default-index has created the index.
even then field is not_analyzed.